# nHibernate join based on property set at query time

Tags: nhibernate, join, icriteria

I need to set a boolean value on my mapped class, based on a parameter set at run time.

In normal SQL I would achieve it as below:

```
select * from resource r,
case when k.resource_key is null then 0 else 1 end as owned,
left outer join resource k
     on k.resource_key = r.resource_key and k.member_key = 719469993
where r.member_key = 167367873
```

What I am trying to achieve here is joining the resource table with itself to find out whether 2 given users both own the same resource.

We are using ICriteria in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<formula>` in your mapping.
I assumes that you have a mapping of an object to resource table, let's call it Resource, and the member_key and resource_key are mapped respectfully to ResourceKey and MemberKey properties in Resource.

```
    <class name="Resource" table="resource" >
       <property name="MemberKey">
          <column name="member_key "/>
       </property>
       <property name="ResourceKey ">
          <column name="resource_key "/>
       </property>
       <property name="Owned">
          <formula>(select case when exists(select * from resource R where R.resource_key = ResourceKey and R.member_key = MemberKey) then 0 else 1 end)</formula>
       </property>
     </class>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's the join im struggling with, not sure how to build the join: 'on k.resource_key = r.resource_key and k.member_key = 719469993'

Comment: Thanks again, this needs to scale to thousands of rows, so im not sure a subselect would perform. We would prefer a join.

Comment: Also, the member key you refer to is not part of the mapping. There are two members in this case, the member who's resources we are viewing, and the current user. Effectively what I am querying is 'show me all the resources this guy owns, but also tell me if i own it too'